# Can I respond with javascript instead of HTML by link?

Tags: javascript, php, html, href

I have lot of HTML pages containing links to same URL address like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/page.php?params=1">Link</a>
```

The question is: **Can I return a javascript response instead of plain HTML that can be executed by clicking on a link?**

For example, I tried this in `page.php`:

```
header("Location: javascript:alert(1)", true, 302);
```

but it doesn't work. If I send the HTML page containing the required javascript, then the browser opens a new page or replaces the current page with this blank page containing the JS.

**Is there any other method to do this without changing link's href?** It seems like it can't because of security restrictions.

Comment: Well the response page could include javascript that runs on page load, but that still means a new page needs to be opened. If you want your current page to execute the JS, then you need to have a function that gets the link page response, and runs it (possibly with `eval()` but I have never had a requirement to do this so not sure how wise it is)

Comment: Are you asking how to use [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)?

Comment: Or are you asking how to invoke a javascript when the page loads, or are you asking how to use javascript to load a new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot invoke JavaScript from the server-side. You can, however, have JavaScript loaded that makes calls to the server and retrieves data.

With that in mind you can have a call to retrieve JSON or XML from the server in which a payload resides that can be extracted by a JavaScript function that is already defined on the client-side.

```
// note: in this example I use jQuery because their AJAX API is terrific
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/page.php?params=1"
})
.done(function( data ) {
    // data is our payload
    doSomethingWithPayload(data);
});
```

That way `doSomethingWithPayload` already is defined on the client, and is called whenever the payload is received.